# Inconsistent accessibility: field type

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, azure-worker-roles

I am trying to connect to CRM 2011 on premise from windows azure worker role through WCF web services. I have created a WCF webservice. But while running the application it is showing error as "`Inconsistent accessibility: field type SampleData_WcfService.OrganizationServiceProxy' is less accessible than field 'SampleData_WcfService.Service1._SDKObject".` I have written the code as

```
namespace SampleData_WcfService
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
    public static OrganizationServiceProxy _SDKObject;
       public bool CRMCall()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!CRM_Connection("http://orgname/dattgtdev/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc", "false", "user2", "pwd", "domain"))
                    return false;

                Entity _entity = new Entity();
                _entity.LogicalName = "account";
                _entity.Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("name", "Testing123456787"));

               _SDKObject.Create(_entity);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
                           }
        }

  public bool CRM_Connection(string WebServiceURL, string Authentication, string UserName, string Password,string DomainName)
        {
            try
            {
                Uri organizationUri = new Uri(WebServiceURL);
                Uri homeRealmUri = null;
               System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials credentials = new System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials();
                if (Authentication == "false")
                {
                    credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, Password, DomainName);
                }

                _SDKObject = new OrganizationServiceProxy(organizationUri, homeRealmUri, credentials, null);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Whats wrong with this code??

Comment: That's odd. `OrganizationServiceProxy` class is supposed to be `public`. How are you referencing CRM's types, is it SDK or a definition created by `CrmSvcUtil` ?

Comment: It is referincing through sdk

Comment: I tried your code on my machine on one of our CRM development environments and it works just fine so I'd say your code is ultimately correct. It has to be Azure's fault somehow but unfortunately I don't have any means of testing it. I'd try to ask on Microsoft forums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_SDKObject` is public, while the `OrganizationServiceProxy` class will most probably be internal. Make the class accesor public, or make the `_SDKObject` declaration less accesible, like internal, protected or private.

Comment: I'm sorry to say it, but this answer doesn't really make much sense since OrganizationServiceProxy is defined as public and part of the platform itself...

Comment: @Alex that might be true, but then the compiler wouldn't throw this error.

Comment: I tried making _SDKObject as internal. And now it is showing error as "SampleData_WcfService.OrganizationServiceProxy' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments".. But I am wondering that I am passing those 4 arguments and why OrganizationServiceproxy is not accepting it and throwing an error

Comment: @user662503 `SampleData_WcfService.OrganizationServiceProxy` ... so you have a class called `OrganizationServiceProxy` in your namespace (perhaps a too eager `Ctrl+.`, `Enter` which created the class in your namespace?). Use `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy`.

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't get what you mean by that?? I am new to Dot net and just started learning

Comment: I tried Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy. But it is showing "A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy' is a type not a namespace"

Comment: @user662503 the exception states that the `OrganizationServiceProxy` class comes from the `SampleData_WcfService` namespace, which is **your** namespace. So you will have to have created such a class, which does not contain a constructor that takes four arguments. Remove the class and add a `using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client` statement, or change the `_SDKObject` declaration to `public static Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy _SDKObject;`. Please learn to read exception messages, since they're usually really clear about what is going wrong.

Comment: As you said I have declared it as public static Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy _SDKObject; and I have also included the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client. But it is still showing error as "SampleData_WcfService.OrganizationServiceProxy' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments

Comment: @user662503 that is because you're still calling the constructor of your own class. Take a look in your solution and remove the OrganizationServiceProxy class.